Terminal shell working, trigger by sh launchd not working
I have a bash script on macOS 10.15 that tides up my download folder. Start it with terminal works fine. Start as a launchAgent with a sh command doesn't work.
#!/bin/bash

#mDate=$(date -j -v-1d +"%s")                               #Epochal date - 1 day
eDate=$(date +%s)                                           #Epochal date
cDate=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)                                     #Current date
fDir=$HOME/Downloads/Browsers/

for x in $fDir*; do
    if [[ $(basename "$x") =~ ^[0-9-]+$ ]]; then :
    elif [ $[$eDate - $(date -r "$x" "+%s")] -gt 172800 ];then
        mkdir -p "$fDir$cDate" && mv "$x" "$fDir$cDate"
    fi
done

This error message returns:
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
[-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
/Users/air/Library/Scripts/BrowserDLbyDate2: line 16: 1727769016 - : syntax error: operand expected (error token is " ")
This looks like something does prohibit "for x in $fDir*" to iterate through the directory.
Line 16 is: elif [ $[$eDate - $(date -r "$x" "+%s")] -gt 172800 ];then
Even started with TextMate.app the script works perfect.

When you use sh to run a Bash script, that's what you get.

As an aside, for x in "$fDir"*[!0-9-]*; do would allow you to remove the first if entirely. As a further tangent, always quote your variables. With that change, this would also be a valid sh script.

I changed it to "bash #HOME/me/browser_script" insteaf of "sh #HOME..." still the script doesn't run. Same error log.

I'm hesitant to reopen this without more debugging details. Can you run it with sh -x and include the output from a successful run (ideally with a single matching file)? How exactly are you running it from a launch agent?

Successful startet with Terminal
++ date +%s

eDate=1727842219
++ date +%Y-%m-%d
cDate=2024-10-02
fDir=/Users/****/Downloads/Browsers/
for x in '"$fDir"[!0-9-]'
++ date -r /Users/****/Downloads/Browsers/staceydenman1_35 +%s
'[' 773124 -gt 172800 ']'
mkdir -p /Users/****/Downloads/Browsers/2024-10-02
mv /Users//Downloads/Browsers/staceydenman1_35 /Users//Downloads/Browsers/2024-10-02


Unsuccessful startet with launchd (sh or bash same)
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
[-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
/Users/****/Library/Scripts/BrowserDLbyDate2: line 15: 1727842634 - : syntax error: operand expected (error token is " ")

(Please don't respond in comments; then we have to post another comment to tell you to delete the comment and ask you to [edit] the question instead.)

Again, how exactly are you scheduling for this to be run by launchd? Under which user account?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
